# p5.js Play Video inside canvas

Tags: javascript, video, p5.js

So I am trying to use the p5.js createVideo function to add a video to a webpage. The only way I can actually get it to appear on screen is by calling createCanvas(0,0), at which point the video appears. To me, this seems as if createVideo adds the video below the actual canvas. Is there any way to add a video inside the actual canvas using the standard p5.js libraries?

Comment: You can use .position() to place it on top

Comment: Awesome, I used .position() and that works perfectly. Is there any way to scale the video frame?

Comment: mm i dont really know, .size() maybe? I think that will work

Comment: using postion  to place it on top is not the same thing as drawing it to the canvas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.position()` to set the video pos on top of the canvas and `.size()` to scale it. Note that the pos is relative to the page and not the canvas

Comment: Does anyone have a working example of this?